# ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN column_name VARCHAR(50) AFTER col_name not supported in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server, alter-table

I tried the following query in SQL Server 2000 so that I could add a new column after mentioned column.

```
alter table abc ADD dad varchar(50) after parentname
```

But it throws me the following error message

> *Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>
>   Line 1: Incorrect syntax near 'after'.*

Is there any way to do this in SQL Server 2000?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Relying on the ordering of table columns in SQL is never a good idea. Just mention them explicitly in your SELECT / UPDATE statements.

Comment: @Frank Schmitt :I want to select all columns and store it on array of string except first two columns. So that excluding first 2 index columns will make coding much simpler.

Comment: @Frank: Some developers (like me) do care about the visual column order that keeps similar fields next to each other, and some columns at the beginning and others to the end. It's just more 'beautiful' and nicer to work with a logical ordered list. I agree that it should not make any technical difference in a good design.

Answer (score 14):

In SQL Server there is no syntax such.

Just use

```
ALTER TABLE abc ADD dad varchar(50)
```

Comment: thankyou for responding.. but above query will not meet my requirement because i want new column to be placed after column named parentname

Comment: There should be no need of order of the column. If you want to put table at particular order - you will have to do using SQL Server Management Studio and it will recreate complete table (not a good idea at all) or it you will just have to do the same thing in T-SQL where you will create a new table with desired columns and then migrate values from old table and drop old table (this is complex as it requires you to take care of all relations).

Comment: I do order the columns in my tables just the way I order my private/protected fields and methods in a class. There is no need to do it, but i like to keep things tidy. E.g. the PK is always first, followed by FK followed by descriptions (Name, Serials etc.).

Comment: In that case, I think you will have to recreate the table from scratch.

Answer (score 7):

Short answer: there is no order in a table.

A table is a set (an unordered collection) of records, each of which is a set of fields. This is why RDBMS theory prefers the words "record" and "field"  rather than "row" and "column".

If you look at a page of data (for example, by using DBCC PAGE in MSSQL) you will see that the storage order of the fields does not correspond to the order you specified in the CREATE TABLE statement.

Ordering is imposed by a SELECT statement.

My advice is to stop spending energy and time on the neatness of the CREATE TABLE and spend it on the SELECT statements instead.